# Solve second-order ODE using gamma functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the ODE
$$\left(x-k_1\right)\frac{dY}{dx} + \frac{1}{a}x^2\frac{d^2 Y}{d x^2}-Y+k_2=0$$
with boundary conditions $Y\left(k_3\right)=0$ and $\frac{d Y}{d x}\left(\infty\right)=1-b$ (meaning if $x \to \infty$, the derivative approaches $1-b$). Not sure if it helps, but we also have $0\leq b \leq 1$, $a \geq 0$, and $k_2 + k_3 \leq k_1$. $x$ and $Y$ should also both be $\geq 0$.

I came across this equation years ago and remember that the solution involved gamma functions in some form, but otherwise I'm not sure where to start (or even what term to Google).

Would anyone know how to find the solution here?

Comment: I should maybe clarify that $Y$ is a function of $t$, too - hence the PDE label. But since neither the coefs nor the boundary conditions depend on it, the solution shouldn't either (?).

Comment: Have you considered the standard methods of solving ODEs since the equation is independent of $t$?

Comment: Are there more constraints on your constants? Another equation involving the $k$'s?

Comment: This is not a PDEbut an ODE.

Comment: @JJacquelin, thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: @EliBartlett, could you point me to some of these, perhaps? It's been a while. There are no other equations.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(x-k_1\right)\frac{d Y}{d x} + \frac{1}{a}x^2\frac{d^2 Y}{dx^2}-Y+k_2=0$$
Simplification with change of function :
$$Y(x)=y(x)+k_2\quad\implies\quad \left(x-k_1\right)\frac{d y}{d x} + \frac{1}{a}x^2\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-y=0$$
Obviously a simple particular solution is linear on the form $ y_p=\alpha x+\beta$

$\alpha\left(x-k_1\right) -(\alpha x+\beta)=0\quad\implies\quad \beta=-\alpha k_1\quad\implies\quad Y_p=\alpha (x-k_1)$

$\alpha$ is an arbitrary constant.

Knowing a particular solution allows to reduce the order of the ODE with change of function :
$$y(x)=\alpha(x-k_1)Z(x)\quad\implies\quad 
\left(\frac{2}{a}x^2+x-k_1\right)\frac{d Z}{d x}  + \frac{1}{a}x^2\frac{d^2 Z}{dx^2}=0$$

$$z(x)=\frac{d Z}{d x}\quad\implies\quad 
\left(\frac{2}{a}x^2+x-k_1\right)z  + \frac{1}{a}x^2\frac{d z}{dx}=0\quad\text{(See the note at end)}$$
The ODE is separable :

$$ \frac{d z}{z}= \left(-2-\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a k_1}{x^2}\right)dx $$
$$z(x)=c_2\exp\left(\int \left(-2-\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a k_1}{x^2}\right)dx \right)$$
$c_2$ is an arbitrary constant.
$$z(x)=c_2\exp\left(-2x-a\ln|x| -\frac{ak_1}{x}\right)$$
$$Z(x)=c_2\int \exp\left(-2x-a\ln|x| -\frac{ak_1}{x}\right)dx +constant$$
$$y(x)=C_2(x-k_1)\int \exp\left(-2x-a\ln|x| -\frac{ak_1}{x}\right)dx+C_1(x-k_1)$$
$$\boxed{Y(x)=C_1(x-k_1)+k_2+C_2(x-k_1)\int \exp\left(-2x-a\ln|x| -\frac{ak_1}{x}\right)dx}$$
$C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

In the general case the integral cannot be expressed in a finite number of available standard functions. One have to proceed with numerical calculus which implies to specify the numerical values of $k_1$ and $a$.

In the particular case $k_1=0$ the integral is reduced to incomplete gamma function.

NOTE : There is a mistake in this equation as rightly pointed out by Eli Bartlett in comments. Although the calculus is not correct up to the end this doesn't change my conclusion : No explicite analytic solution,  finally one have to proceed with numerical calculus.

I don't delete the wrong part of the calculus in interest of showing the method or reduction of order and the way up to the integral form of solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful! I've got a follow-up question: why doesn't the solution depend on the boundary conditions, i.e., the $b$ and $k_3$ parameters? Alternatively, is there a way to solve for $C_1$ and $C_2$ by using the $b$ and $k_3$ parameters somehow?

Comment: You've lost the factor $(x-k_1)$ when you made the transformation $y=\alpha(x-k_1)Z$, I believe it should come out to $x^2(x-k_1)/a Z''+(2x^2/a+(x-k_1)^2)Z'=0$.

Comment: @Eli Bartlett. You are right there is a mistake. Thanks you very much for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this equation assuming it is a function of $x$ and $t$, but you will find that when constraining to the boundary conditions it is a function of $x$ only, so I'll treat it like an ODE.

For your question I will use the following trick: given a particular solution $u(x)$ to the homogeneous equation
\begin{align}
u''+f_1(x)u'+f_0(x)u=0,
\end{align}

the ODE
\begin{align}
y''+f_1(x)y'+f_0(x)y=f(x)
\end{align}
is exact under the integrating factor $e^{F_1}u$, where $F_1(x)=\smallint f_1(x)\mathrm dx$. Note that there is a term of the form $xy'-y$, so you should try to find a linear particular solution to your equation. We find that $Y_0=x-k_1$ works. So for your ODE
\begin{align}
Y''+a\frac{x-k_1}{x^2}Y'-\frac{a}{x^2}y+\frac{ak_1}{x^2}=0,
\end{align}
multiply by $(x-k_1)x^ae^{ak_1/x}$ to arrive at
\begin{align}
\left((x-k_1)x^ae^{ak_1/x}Y'-x^ae^{ak_1/x}Y\right)'+ak_1\frac{x-k_1}{x^2}e^{ak_1/x}=0.
\end{align}
Integrating and rearranging we arrive at
\begin{align}
Y'-\frac{1}{x-k_1}Y+\frac{k_1}{x-k_1}=\frac{c_1}{(x-k_1)x^ae^{ak_1/x}}.
\end{align}
This ODE is exact under the integrating factor $1/(x-k_1)$, multiplying, integrating, and rearranging we arrive at
\begin{align}
Y(x)=k_1+(x-k_1)\left(c_2+c_1\mathcal I(x)\right);\quad\left[\mathcal I(x)=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x-k_1)^2x^ae^{ak_1/x}}\right].
\end{align}
We see that we recover the particular solution $Y_0=k_1+c(x-k_1)$ here as well. Now to fit the solution to the constraints. Evaluating $Y(x)$ at $k_3$ and letting $x\rightarrow\infty$ in $Y'(x)$ we get the equations
\begin{align}
\mathcal I(k_3)c_1+c_2&=\frac{k_1}{k_1-k_3},\\
\mathcal I(\infty)c_1+c_2&=1-b;\quad\left[\mathcal I(\infty)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal I(x)\right].
\end{align}
Which have the solutions
\begin{align}
c_1&=\frac{1}{\mathcal I(k_3)-\mathcal I(\infty)}\left(\frac{k_1}{k_1-k_3}+b-1\right),\\
c_2&=\frac{1}{\mathcal I(k_3)-\mathcal I(\infty)}\left(\frac{k_1}{k_1-k_3}\mathcal I(\infty)+(1-b)\mathcal I(k_3)\right).
\end{align}
So our solution is
\begin{align}
Y(x)=k_1+\frac{x-k_1}{\mathcal I(k_3)-\mathcal I(\infty)}\left((1-b)(\mathcal I(k_3)-\mathcal I(x))+\frac{k_1}{k_1-k_3}(\mathcal I(x)-\mathcal I(\infty))\right);\\\\\left[\mathcal I(x)=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x-k_1)^2x^ae^{ak_1/x}}\right].
\end{align}
What I've been ignoring is the singularity in $\mathcal I(x)$. If the domain of $x$ includes $k_1$, the integral is divergent. This is why I ask if there are more constraints on your $k$'s! If we restrict our $x$ domain to $[k_3,\infty)$ (as your boundary conditions imply), then we require that $k_3>k_1$ for $x>k_1$.

Comment: Thank you, @EliBartlett! I'll need some time to go over this in more detail. One thing to ask: in your last sentence, you say that $k_3 > k_1$. Given that we require $k_2+k_3 \leq k_1$, will this solution only work if $k_2 < 0$? I'll need to check but I think all the $k$s should be non-negative. Apologies for not mentioning this before.

Comment: Yes. If $k_2>0$, $k_3$ must be smaller than $k_1$ which messes things up. What is the origin of your problem?

Comment: The problem is a generalized version of the Black-Scholes equation: $\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial x^2}+\left(rx - C\right)\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}-rY+c.$ Dividing this by $r$, I get $\frac{1}{a}x^2\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial x^2}+\left(x - k_1\right)\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}-Y+k_2$, with $a=2r / \sigma^2$, $k_1=C/r$ and $k_2=c/r$.

$Y$ here is firm's equity. $c$ is the payout to equity whereas $C$ is the overall payout. $k_3$ from the boundary condition is another payout divided by $r$ and means that if $x$ is equal to it or below it, the equity has 0 value.

Comment: So, $C$ is the total payout which includes the equity payout plus the one the boundary condition is based on. This means that $k_1 \geq k_2 + k_3$. This whole exercise is in the spirit of "A contingent-claims valuation of convertible securities" by Ingersoll (1977), but he uses slightly different assumptions. So maybe my version cannot be solved.

Comment: I think you swapped $k_2$ with $k_1$ in the "So for your ODE..." part.